# Conversion using std::decay_t

Tags: c++, std

I have some code but I do not understand what does it do

```
template <typename T, typename U = T>
struct MyStruct
{
};

template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] inline T fromValue(const QJsonValue& json)
{
    return MyStruct<std::decay_t<T>>::get(json);
}
```

I do not understand what heppenes in line

```
return MyStruct<std::decay_t<T>>::get(json);
```

And Why we use empty struct?

Comment: The struct template is probably specialized elsewhere. `decay_t` strips const/volatile/&/&& from the type, and converts arrays to pointers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You use `std::decay_t` in order to obtain the basic type without cv-qualification (plus some fewer used special features for arrays and function pointers). Starting from C++20, for most cases it should be sufficient to use `std::remove_cvref_t<T>` for this.

The function signature

```
template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] inline T fromValue(const QJsonValue& json)
{
    return MyStruct<std::decay_t<T>>::get(json);
}
```

basically tells you, that regardless of the cv-qualification (`T`, `T&`, `T const&`, `T volatile const&`, etc.) the class template should be instantiated only with the base type `T`. Thereafter, the static function `get` is called -- *static* because those are functions that can be called without an object.

EDIT: sorry, I just recognized that the struct is empty. So your code won't work, as there simply is no `get` function available.

Note however, that there is a danger of returning a dangling reference here, because for `T&` as template parameter, you return a reference. Moreover, you don't want `const`s, `volatile`s, etc. in your return type. Therefore I would question the design of this function and use it with caution.